# How can i logout from android application

Tags: android

I am new to android. I want code for logout from my application .I use shared preferences in my application. I want to put logout facility in my appplication.

Comment: If you implemented a login mechanism, surely you can implement a logout mechanism?

Comment: Please show what you have done (code-wise) and any errors that may have occurred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yuu can clear the `SharedPreference` on Logout which you have set during login.
`OnClick` of Logout:

```
SharedPreferences sf = getSharedPreferences("UserLogin", MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor edt = sf.edit();
            edt.putString("UserName", "");
            edt.putString("PassWord", "");
            edt.commit();
```

Hope this will help you...

Comment: And this code log you out of any android application that is there in this world.

Comment: Thanks....for appreciating my ans...

Comment: what if i have some other activity in between. Like I have Login screen. I log in. I get an activity say, A activity. From there I go to activity B from where I log out. After logging out I want all the other activities to be cleared.

Comment: For that override **onResume()** method in all activity and check for the username and password from the preferences if username and password are empty then just finish the activity.